# Set body class based on url with params

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to set a body class based on the url - I can get it to work with a plain `/Tablet/` url, like the code below.

But I need to set it to a url that has params in it, and I can't get that to work. How do I do it with this url?

> `/Tablets/?param=grid&pld0page=1&spcs=1`

Script:

```
$(function() {
  var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
  if(/Tablets/.test(loc)) {
    $('body').addClass('test');
  }
});
```

Comment: Quite confusing. Can you rephrase ?

Comment: Confusing? I want to set a body class if the url is /Tablets/?param=grid&pld0page=1&spcs=1

Comment: So if the URL is **exactly** that? Does the order of query parameters matter?

Comment: Exactly like that @Phil

Comment: You didn't answer my second question. Does the order of query parameters matter? I ask as the order is usually not important

Comment: @JerrySvensson are you looking for a specific parameter in query params or combination? Please explain use-cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you have mentioned in comments, the query parameter order **is** important, you can use this...

```
var url = location.pathname + location.search
console.info(url)

$(document.body).toggleClass('test',
  url === '/Tablets/?param=grid&pld0page=1&spcs=1')
```

This lets you omit the URL scheme, host and port parts, focusing only on the path and query parameters.

Comment: Hmm. It founds the body, but dont add the class.

Comment: @JerrySvensson what is the URL? I've added some example debugging code. Check your console

Comment: Ok that works. My url was /products/Computers/Tablets/?param=grid&pld0page=1&spcs=1, I thought it was enough with the tablet part - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$(function() {
 var url = window.location.href;
   url = url.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '')
  if(url == '/Tablets?param=grid&pld0page=1&spcs=1') {
    $('body').addClass('test');
  }
});
```

If your URL is "http://www.google.com/?param=grid&pld0page=1&spcs=1", then the above queryString variable would be equal to `"?param=grid&pld0page=1&spcs=1".`

You can check the string is not empty

Comment: @JerrySvensson i have update dthe answer. Please check if it works for you

Comment: Glad! I could help.

Comment: This completely ignores the path part of the URI. OP said they want it to match `/Tablets/?...`. What happened to that?

Comment: Actually - that dont work- It does add the class or if i change the url it still adds the class - /Tablet/?param=grid&pld0page=1&spcs=2 would give the same result as /Tablet/?param=grid&pld0page=1&spcs=1

Comment: @JerrySvensson If you want the exact value of  `/Tablets?param=grid&pld0page=1&spcs=1`, then you can use the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You just have to search for text you want in the url string. You are doing fine in the code above. Just change

```
$(function() {
  var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
  if(loc.includes('Tablets')) { // will return true/false
    $('body').addClass('test');
  }
});
```

Read on [includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). You can do the same for other tests too, if you are checking for other strings in url. Hope this helps.

Comment: This will match if `Tablets` appears **anywhere** in the URL, eg `?param=grid&pld0page=1&spcs=2&Tablets=Tablets`

Comment: you can give specific pattern to the search if you want.

Comment: @Phil and looking at the question it seems there should be switch between classes if it has 'Tablets' in the url. I'm certain the above snippet would do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var loc = 'http://localhost/Tablets/?param=grid&pld0page=1&spcs=35';
var patt = new RegExp("/Tablets/");

if(patt.test(loc) && loc.split('?').length > 1)
{
console.log('true');
$('body').addClass('test');

}
else
{
console.log('false');
$('body').removeClass('test');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

```
var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
var url = loc.split( '/' );
var chunk = url[ url.length - 2 ];
if(loc.indexOf(chunk) >= 0) {
    $('body').addClass('test');
}
```